# Preventing a member function from being called alone

Tags: c++, function, class

In this code:

```
class Person {
    std::string name;
public:
    Person(const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    void setName(const std::string& newName) {name = newName;}
};

class System {
    void changeName (Person* person, const std::string& newName) {
        person->setName(newName);  // The obvious necessary line.
        // A bunch of very important changes due to the name change.
    }
};
```

Whenever a person changes his name, a bunch of changes must be made in `System`.  Without those other changes, everything will collapse.  However, it is easy to forget this and accidentally call `Person::setName` by itself by accident.  How to make that impossible?  I thought of the key-pass idiom, but that still does not prevent `Person` from calling its own `Person::setName` function (I also don't want `System` to be friend of `Person`).  If such a safeguard is impossible, how to redesign this so that such an accident cannot happen (and it likely will, because my memory is not that good)?

Comment: Why won't you invert calls and call changeName from setName instead?

Comment: If you don't want the function to be able to be called then it probably should not be public at all

Comment: @ Estiny.  Yes, that is an obvious solution that I should have thought of.  `changeName` will have to be public in `System` now though.

Comment: Why would you have a public `person` class if handling it directly compromises the integrity of the system? Looks more like a design issue than a C++ one to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [the Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). In the most basic version, make each `Person` hold a pointer to a `System`, and when `setName()` of a person is called, notify the `System`, so that it does some very important changes:

```
class System; // forward declaration
class Person {
    std::string name;
    System* system;

public:
    Person(const std::string& n, System* s) : name(n), system(s) {}
    void setName(const std::string& newName);
};

class System {
public:
    void changeName (Person* person, const std::string& newName) {
        person->setName(newName);  // The obvious necessary line.
    }
    void onNameChange(Person* person) {
        // A bunch of very important changes due to the name change.
    }
};

void Person::setName(const std::string& newName) {
    name = newName;
    system->onNameChange(this); // notify the system
}
```